# Is there more efficient way to randomize and then combine 3 subsets of data with an even distribution?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I made a simple app for my local writing group that "randomly" splits the group in half in order to decide if they are in the orange room or the blue room. What I have works, and the number of people is never more than 20, but I know it's a brute force method that wouldn't hold up for very large numbers.

I've tried to leave good comments for this method, but if there is any confusion I'll happily update the question.

```
// Splits people into three groups, anchors, people with pages, and people without pages. Then it evenly(as possible) distributes people with and without pages into two groups.
public ArrayList<Person> shuffle() {

    ArrayList<Person> haveNoPages = new ArrayList<>(); // people who don't have pages, including anchors.
    ArrayList<Person> anchorList = new ArrayList<>(); // people who are Anchors.

    // Split people who don't have pages
    for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++){
        if(people.get(i).getPages().equals("0")){
            haveNoPages.add(people.get(i));
            people.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    // holds the anchors temporarily
    for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
        if (people.get(i).isBlueA() || people.get(i).isOrangeA()) {
            anchorList.add(people.get(i));
            people.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    // Randomize the lists to "draw" names.
    Collections.shuffle(people);
    Collections.shuffle(haveNoPages);

    // Alternate group placement until the list is empty.
    for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            people.get(i).setGroup("Orange");
        } else {
            people.get(i).setGroup("Blue");
        }
    }

    // Alternate group placement until the list is empty.
    for (int i = 0; i < haveNoPages.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            haveNoPages.get(i).setGroup("Orange");
        } else {
            haveNoPages.get(i).setGroup("Blue");
        }
    }

    // Recombine the list and return it.
    people.addAll(anchorList);
    people.addAll(haveNoPages);
    anchorList.clear();
    haveNoPages.clear();
    return people;
}
```

My initial thoughts are to combine everything into a single for loop and then use booleans to alternate the blue and orange groups between each type of person. Example:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0 && !people.get(i).isBlueA() && !people.get(i).isOrangeA()) {
            people.get(i).setGroup("Orange");
        } else if (!people.get(i).isBlueA() && !people.get(i).isOrangeA()) {
            people.get(i).setGroup("Blue");
        }
    }
```

The problem with this solution is that I don't know how to make sure people with no pages get lumped together in a useless group. I need each "type" to be evenly distributed.

**Example of a poorly sorted group:**

**Blue Group**

- Katy - 0 Pages
- Bart - 0 Pages
- Pages Alice (Anchor) - 0 Pages

**Orange Group**

- Alex - 5 Pages
- Marissa - 6 Pages
- John (Anchor) - 2 Pages

Hopefully this makes it clear as to why I resorted to sorting and distributing groups to each subset individually. I need to make sure there are an even number of people with pages in each group so one group doesn't get left twiddling their thumbs.

I eventually want to go one step further and figure out a way to have the number of pages each person brings to be considered, but that's something to worry about later.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about something similar the other day.  About how to use a 'transient' list with counters.

Basically, keep a running tally of {Anchor, >0, =0} with 3 separate counters.  As you iterate over the people list, determine the type, check the counter with modulo to determine blue or orange and then increment.

```
// Evenly(as possible) distributes people with and without pages into two groups.
public ArrayList<Person> shuffle() {

    int anAnchorCount = 0; // useless?
    int hasPagesCount = 0;
    int emptyHanded = 0;

    // Split people who don't have pages
    for(Person p : people){
        if (p.isBlueA() || p.isOrangeA()){
            // skip ?? ... Already assigned?
            anAnchorCount++;
        }
        else if(p.getPages().equals("0")){
            p.setGroup((emptyHanded++ % 2 == 0) ? "Orange" : "Blue");
        }
        else
            p.setGroup((hasPagesCount++ % 2 == 0) ? "Orange" : "Blue");
    }

    return people;
}
```

It that works, then it would be O(N).

---

Later on, you can use buckets to distribute evenly based on number of pages.  Your `if/elseif/else` tree would just check for ranges.